# Passing arguments to iterated function through apply

Tags: r

I have a function like this dummy-one:

```
FUN <- function(x, parameter){
  if (parameter == 1){
      z <- DO SOMETHING WITH "x"}
  if (parameter ==2){
      z <- DO OTHER STUFF WITH "x"}
return(z)
}
```

Now, I would like to use the function on a dataset using apply.
The problem is, that `apply(data,1,FUN(parameter=1))`

wont work, as FUN doesn't know what "x" is.
Is there a way to tell apply to call FUN with "x" as the current row/col?
`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want `apply(data,1,FUN,parameter=1)`.  Note the `...` in the function definition:

```
> args(apply)
function (X, MARGIN, FUN, ...) 
NULL
```

and the corresponding entry in the documentation:

> ...: optional arguments to ‘FUN’.

Answer (score 17):

You can make an anonymous function within the call to `apply` so that FUN will know what "x" is:

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) FUN(x, parameter = 1))
```

See `?apply` for examples at the bottom that use this method.

Comment: @Gavin - I guess I don't appreciate the difference in clarity or performance stand point. The R docs are pretty clear that the `...` are for additional parameters to `FUN` so point duly noted. However, it's just a small leap in complexity to needing that anonymous function capability and I'm guessing the OP didn't know about that "trick" previously.

Comment: Indeed, hence a comment and not a down-vote. Nothing wrong with what you wrote at all. Wasn't meant as criticism.

Comment: Actually, I sounded like and arse and that wasn't the intention. I'm going to delete that comment. The substantive bit (so the other comments mean something) was; you could do the same a bit simpler with `apply(data, 1, FUN, parameter = 1)`

Comment: Hah, no worries and no offense taken. I think it's good to take a step back sometimes and make sure your fundamental operating assumptions about a mundane task are sound. I honestly had forgotten all about the `...` so it was good to reconsider that for a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a practical example of passing arguments using the `...` object and `*apply`. It's slick, and this seemed like an easy example to explain the use.    An important point to remember is when you define an argument as `...` all calls to that function must have named arguments. (so R understands what you're trying to put where). For example, I could have called `times <- fperform(longfunction, 10, noise = 5000)` but leaving off `noise =` would have given me an error because it's being passed through `...`  My personal style is to name all of the arguments if a `...` is used just to be safe.

You can see that the argument `noise` is being defined in the call to `fperform(FUN = longfunction, ntimes = 10, noise = 5000)` but isn't being used for another 2 levels with the call to `diff <- rbind(c(x, runtime(FUN, ...)))` and ultimately `fun <- FUN(...)`

```r
# Made this to take up time
longfunction <- function(noise = 2500, ...) {
  lapply(seq(noise), function(x) {
    z <- noise * runif(x)
  })
}

# Takes a function and clocks the runtime
runtime <- function(FUN, display = TRUE, ...) {
  before <- Sys.time()
  fun <- FUN(...)
  after <- Sys.time()
  if (isTRUE(display)) {
    print(after-before)
  }
  else {
    after-before
  }
}

# Vectorizes runtime() to allow for multiple tests
fperform <- function(FUN, ntimes = 10, ...) {   
  out <- sapply(seq(ntimes), function(x) {
    diff <- rbind(c(x, runtime(FUN, ...)))
  })
}

times <- fperform(FUN = longfunction, ntimes = 10, noise = 5000)

avgtime <- mean(times[2,])
print(paste("Average Time difference of ", avgtime, " secs", sep=""))
```