# How to add optional argument to function in lapply in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I am using the following:

```
qicout <- matrix(unlist(lapply(X = cand.set, FUN = qic)), length(cand.set), 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

It has worked, but I have changes the function qic so it now has an argument

```
qic(model, small = TRUE)
```

I would like to adjust the lapply function above to include TRUE or FALSE within qic. This lapply function to calculate qicout is actually within another function and I would like to have an option of small = TRUE/FALSE so it can be passed to the qic function within lapply. Any suggestions of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think:

```
cout <- matrix(unlist(lapply(X = cand.set, FUN = qic, small = TRUE )), 
    length(cand.set), 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

should work or `small = FALSE` but I may not understand correctly.

Comment: +1  [similar for the whole family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792896/passing-arguments-to-iterated-function-through-apply)

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I kept trying to add the small argument inside parentheses like FUN = qic(small = FALSE) and things like that.